# Xampp MySql isn't starting (mac)

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

When I start Mysql from Xampp nothing happens. 
Here are the logs:

```
2015-02-12 20:45:14 6090 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Thomass-MacBook-Air.local.pid ended
2015-02-12 20:49:20 6770 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
2015-02-12 20:49:21 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-02-12 20:49:21 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/mysql/ib7sYHPC' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7fff738e6310  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned      error.
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-02-12 20:49:21 7138 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

**Edit:** Thanks for you quick responses guys!

I reinstalled XAMPP and everything is running fine now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to chmod (change the permissions) the directory so that mysql can write to it. You'll notice the error code also mentions this:

```
Can't create/write to file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/mysql/ib7sYHPC' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

It might also matter how you are starting it. Try this from a terminal:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/mysql
```

Comment: I know this ^ is from 2015, but please **DO NOT use chmod 777**

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it was in my logfile with name:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/<User>.lan.err
```

In the logfile I found the log-message:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ib_logfile0 can't be opened in read-write mode
```

Then I went to this directory and executed the following command in order to change permissions to rw for all users on 2 logfiles:

```
chmod +666 ib_logfile0 
chmod +666 ib_logfile1
```

After that, I executed the `ls -l command and my -rw-rw-rw are correct:`

```
-rw-rw-rw-   1 PerEskilson  admin  50331648 Oct 19 23:17 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw-rw-   1 PerEskilson  admin  50331648 Oct 12 13:24 ib_logfile1
```

When this was done my database started fine.

Comment: Wow this actually worked! The way I did it was by pressing command i on the file to get info and changing the permissions from there using the interface.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening due to the program not instaling correctly, try uninstalling it and then installing it again, make sure all of the files are removed (the temp. files and shortcuts) to ensure that they are not causing the problem.

Hope this fixes the problem - Jim